# show more info when click a button html, css, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a code where i have one box and when i click the button it actually shows more or less info. See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/075tcezL/

```
/css
#model {
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
margin: 20px 10px;
padding: 0 5px;
float: left;
max-height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;


-webkit-transition: max-height 0.7s;
-moz-transition: max-height 0.7s;
transition: max-heigth 0.7s;

}
#show-more {
display: block;
background-color: #75868E;
width: 100px;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
margin: 20px auto;
cursor: pointer;
height: 15px;
padding: 10px 0; 
}

#model.open {
max-height: 1000px;

-webkit-transition: max-heigth 0.7s;
-moz-transition: max-heigth 0.7s;
transition: max-heigth 0.7s;
}
```

//HTML

```
<body>
<div id="model" class="model1">
    <h3>Series 3</h3>
        <a href="#series3" id="sseries"><img class="image" 
            src="image"></a>

<p>Text to hide or show.</p>

</div>                      
<a id="show-more" class="show">Show More</a>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>
```

//This works with one box

```
var content = document.getElementById("model");
var button = document.getElementById("show-more")

button.onclick = function(){

if(content.className == "open"){
    content.className = "";
    button.innerHTML = "More";

} else {
    content.className = "open";
    button.innerHTML = "Less";
}

};
```

But if i have three boxes, like this - https://jsfiddle.net/jw7pfb1w/
How do i open or close them at the same time when clicking on that button?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are required to place your minimal example of the problem code here, not a jsfiddle that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added problem code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName('.model1');` to select all elements on the page with the same class:

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("model1");
var button = document.getElementById("show-more");

button.onclick = function(){
    for (i = 0; i < content.length; ++i) {      
      if(content[i].className == "model1 open"){
        content[i].className = "model1";
        button.innerHTML = "More";
    } else {
        content[i].className = "model1 open";
        button.innerHTML = "Less";
    }  
  }
};
```

You'll also need the CSS for `open` in your 3 panel example:

```
div.open {
    max-height: 1000px;
    -webkit-transition: max-heigth 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: max-heigth 0.7s;
    transition: max-heigth 0.7s;
}
```

Added a working fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/jw7pfb1w/5/

Comment: Updated for you. You may want to look in to jQuery as that can make this sort of UI functionality much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same method three times, or do a loop.

For achieve that, you can place in your html, multiple ids with numbers.
Like model1, model2, model3, ...

```js
var button = document.getElementById("show-more")

button.onclick = function(){

 // we loop three times for three blocks
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // i + 1 -> 1, 2, 3
    // so model1, then model2, then model3

    // using concatenation string "model" + the number
    var content = document.getElementById("model" + (i + 1));

    // using toggle function will add the class if not present, else remove it.
    var isOpen = content.classList.toggle('open');

    button.innerHTML = isOpen ? "More" : "Less";
  }

};
```

```css
.model {
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
 margin: 20px 10px;
 padding: 0 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 max-height: 100px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.open {
 max-height: 1000px !important; 
}
```

```html
<button id="show-more">More</button>
<div>
  <div class="model" id="model1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="model" id="model2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="model" id="model3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</div>
```